# What is the default behavior in PHP 5.4 regarding the Safe Mode

Tags: php, installation, safe-mode

I am a little confused and need some input here:

From what I know, with the Safe Mode directive set to off, PHP was able to access files even if the owner was different.

Then setting to On, access to those files was disabled.

Now in PHP 5.4 the Safe Mode is removed and I can't find what is the default functionality comparing to the past.

Tried to change permissions to a file not owned by the Server, didn't work... so should I consider that the default functionality is like having Safe Mode On?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default functionality in PHP 5.4 is having no Safe Mode at all.

That is similar to the past when the Safe Mode directive was set to off.

Whatever is causing your problems, it can not be Safe Mode in PHP 5.4 because there is no Safe Mode any longer. It has been removed.

If you want to find out what causes you headaches, you need to troubleshoot your problem. For example by enabling error logging and reporting to the highest level and following the error log.

- [Error Reporting](http://www.phptherightway.com/#error_reporting)

See as well:

- [where is the security in PHP 5.4 by removing safe_mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9763531/367456)
- [Safe Mode<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/features.safe-mode)
- [Security and Safe Mode<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/ini.sect.safe-mode)

Comment: "That is similar to the past when the Safe Mode directive was set to off." - That is what I wanted to know. Thank you!